# Blender 2.8 model showing random color shading in object mode

Tags: blend-modes

I was creating some building model and lot of work I have done on it, and accidentally, I have press some keys and now my model looks with random colour, can anyone tell me what's the cause of this, is it some settings. I a  am beginner in blender.

[image]

Comment: Looks like z fighting. Do you have a duplicate mesh in the same location? Hide meshes in the outliner one by one to check.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the problem was with duplicate, I accidentally imported the same object instead  of exporting, that's how the duplication happens.